# Programmatically pulling different versions of a file from an SVN repository?

Tags: java, svn, version-control

I would like to be able to pull different versions of a file.

Does subversion support a protocol that allows this ? If not, what documentation could I look into to figure out how to list and retrieve different versions of a file ?

Comment: Doesn't SVN have its own scripting like language?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't know as of yet. I have to research the subject more. I was hoping it might be possible to pull a file through a URL but maybe that won't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

- Use the command line client, and simply call the correct command. In most programming languages, there's some sort of *system* command that allows you to do this. In scripting languages like Windows Batch or BASH, you can simply run the command line client directly from the program.
- Use the [C API](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html)
- Use another implementation that acts as a wrapper to the API, or emulates the API (like [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) does).

You didn't mention the language you're *scripting* in. Most languages have their own Subversion interface. Java can use either [SVNkit](http://svnkit.com/) or [JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL). C can use the C API directly. C# has [SVN.net](http://pumacode.org/53/). Python has [Pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/). Perl has [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.7.3.1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm).

Here's how to get a particular revision of a file via the standard command line in Unix/Linux/Mac:

```
$ svn cat -r$SVN_REVISION $URL_TO_FILE_NAME > $FILE_NAME
```

The `svn cat` command prints out the file you want. The `-r` specifies the Subversion revision (otherwise, `HEAD` -- the latest version on that branch -- will be used).

Remember too that if you're pulling up a file based upon a tag, there is no need for a `-r` parameter since the URL contains the tag you want. To pull up a file based upon a tag:

```
$ svn cat $SERVER_URL/tags/$TAG_NAME/$PATH_TO_FILE > $FILE_NAME
```

The client program is called `svn` and `svn help` will give you all the various subcommands. Also, the [online Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) explains how the command line works.

Comment: Using command line is a good suggestion. I don't know about the scripting language. I see the subversion plugin on Eclipse uses SVNKit ? I guess I should practice with the command line a bit to see how it works.

Comment: SVNKit isn't a "scripting language", it's a full SVN client API implementation in Java.

Comment: SVNKit is a pure Java API. If you're using Java, you can use the SVNKit.jar as part of your Java program to access your Subversion repository much like Eclipse does. ***HOWEVER***, if you download SVNKit, you will see several shell script examples of accessing SVNKit right from the command line. Of course, if you do that, you might as well just use the command line client itself.